# Using any in nested ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, any

**data:**

```
set.seed(1337)
m <- matrix(sample(c(0,0,0,1),size = 50,replace=T),ncol=5) %>% as.data.frame
colnames(m)<-LETTERS[1:5]
```

**code:**

```
m %<>%
        mutate(newcol       = ifelse(A==1&(B==1|C==1)&(D==1|E==1),1,
                                     ifelse(any(A,B,C,D,E),0,NA)),
               desiredResult= ifelse(A==1&(B==1|C==1)&(D==1|E==1),1,
                                     ifelse(!(A==0&B==0&C==0&D==0&E==0),0,NA)))
```

**looks like:**

```
   A B C D E newcol desiredResult
1  0 1 1 1 0      0             0
2  0 1 0 0 1      0             0
3  0 1 0 0 0      0             0
4  0 0 0 0 0      0            NA
5  0 1 0 1 0      0             0
6  0 0 1 0 0      0             0
7  1 1 1 1 0      1             1
8  0 1 1 0 0      0             0
9  0 0 0 0 0      0            NA
10 0 0 1 0 0      0             0
```

**question**

I want `newcol` to be the same as `desiredResult`.

Why can't I use `any` in that "stratified" manner of `ifelse`. Is there a function like `any` that would work in that situation?

**possible workaround**

I could define a function
`any_vec <- function(...) {apply(cbind(...),1,any)}` but this does not make me smile too much.

**like suggested in the answer**

using `pmax` works exactly like a vectorized `any`.

```
m %>%
    mutate(pmaxResult = ifelse(A==1& pmax(B,C) & pmax(D,E),1,
                                 ifelse(pmax(A,B,C,D,E),0,NA)),
           desiredResult= ifelse(A==1&(B==1|C==1)&(D==1|E==1),1,
                                 ifelse(!(A==0&B==0&C==0&D==0&E==0),0,NA)))
```

Comment: I guess the problem with `any` in `ifelse` is that its return value is length 1 whereas `ifelse` expects a logical vector of the same length as its input.

Comment: which means you should use `if` and `else` instead if your condition is of length 1.

Comment: @Roland, no, the OP _wants_ something like `any` but vectorized. `if/else` isn't going to help here.

Comment: Use `rowSums(m == 1) == 0` instead of `any`?

Comment: @zx8754 yes, or just `ifelse(rowSums(m),0,NA)`

Comment: @Ista I was not looking too closely at the code or details since the question uses dplyr without warning me with an appropriate tag (which would allow me to ignore it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach. I converted to logical at the beginning and back to integer at the end:

```
m %>% 
  mutate_all(as.logical) %>% 
  mutate(newcol       = A & pmax(B,C) & pmax(D, E) ,
         newcol       = replace(newcol, !newcol & !pmax(A,B,C,D,E), NA)) %>% 
  mutate_all(as.integer)

#    A B C D E newcol
# 1  0 1 1 1 0      0
# 2  0 1 0 0 1      0
# 3  0 1 0 0 0      0
# 4  0 0 0 0 0     NA
# 5  0 1 0 1 0      0
# 6  0 0 1 0 0      0
# 7  1 1 1 1 0      1
# 8  0 1 1 0 0      0
# 9  0 0 0 0 0     NA
# 10 0 0 1 0 0      0
```

I basically replaced the `any` with `pmax`.

Comment: I think `pmax` can function as `any` and `pmin` as `all`